# How can I click on this element using XPATH in WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, xpath, click, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML:

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" checked="" name="selectedMstrPrivGroupList[9].mstrAuthorities[0].status"/>
Add Dexter
</li>
```

How could this element be clicked in WebDriver? It is a check box. And I want to use XPath as I have close to 30+ check boxes in the page. So that I can create a generic method and pass only the WebElement. I tried the following but didn't work.

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(.,'Add Dexter')]")).click();
```

Comment: why dont you do it with findElements? Another option could be cssSelectors

Comment: Another option, but they're not the same thing. Please tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the checkbox next to "Add Dexter" is what you want to click on the page, you can use:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Add Dexter')]//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Comment: and if you want to make a generic method out of it, `"//li[contains(.,'" + someString + "')]//input[@type='checkbox']"` should work.

Answer (score 1):

What is with this one:

```
  Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedMstrPrivGroupList[9].mstrAuthorities[0].status']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... This works in this case but I particularly don't want to use the name attribute. Reason: Page is dynamic and associated text changes frequently... So, I was looking for something with which i can click on the check box with its associated text... Thanks again!

Comment: This worked for me.. Thanks for the help..

    Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Add Dexter')]//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Add Dexter')]")).click()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to click on the element as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[text()='Add Dexter']")).click();
```

You can also click on that element by using cssSelector instead of xpath as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input:contains(^Add Dexter$)")).click();
```

Note: CssPath/CssSelector is faster than xpath. So it's better to use cssSelector than xpath in most cases.